# 'FrozenObject.h' file not found while adding RNZebraBluetoothPrinter in React Native iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I am implementing the React Native Zebra Bluetooth Printer in iOS. I have installed the library i.e **[npm i react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-zebra-bluetooth-printer)** After done all the setup specified in the package the build throws error. Anyone please help me here.

Unable to find the FrojezObject.h file.

Build should happen without this error.